# Remove not existing table from MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I removed (dropped) not used (in fact it was corrupted and that's why not used) table from a MySQL DB.
I did it from MySQL Workbench. It was removed and it's not existing here.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cacti.data_debug;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'cacti.data_debug' doesn't exist
```

BUT if I query INFORMATION_SCHEMA, I get this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE name = 'cacti/data_debug';
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+------------+
| TABLE_ID | NAME             | FLAG | N_COLS | SPACE | FILE_FORMAT | ROW_FORMAT | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE |
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|    79055 | cacti/data_debug |   33 |     10 |  6305 | Barracuda   | Dynamic    |             0 | Single     |
+----------+------------------+------+--------+-------+-------------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

I found out that we can only read from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. It's just a list/snapshot of the existing data. I'd like to remove this single "row" as I'm moving to MySQL 8.0 and don't want to drag the mess. On top , Upgrade Checker is complaining about this as Error.

How can I make it refreshed/regenerated?

Update 1:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES FROM cacti;
+-------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_cacti                     |
+-------------------------------------+
| aggregate_graph_templates           |
| aggregate_graph_templates_graph     |
| ...                                 |
| color_templates                     |
| colors                              |
| data_input                          |
| data_input_data                     |
| data_input_fields                   |
| data_local                          |
| data_source_profiles                |
| data_source_profiles_cf             |
| ...                                 |
| version                             |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Show the output for `SHOW TABLES FROM cacti;`.

Comment: Does Workbench have permission to access `cacti`?

Comment: @Akina data is provided in the question now. Rick James, workbench was used just to delete. All queries above are executed from cli by root.

Comment: SHOW TABLES reports that there is no such table. Try to create fake table with this name then drop it..

Comment: @Akina I tried this before. I got "ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`cacti`.`data_debug`' already exists".

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

Comment: So, thanks to this answer above I managed to make fake table data_debug and include into cacti DB. It's not fully nice, but at least Update Checker is not complaining. I will try to remove this table in the process of migration. Thanks all!